# Is it possible to mark an outlook calendar event as "Busy" for some attendees and "Free" for others using the Microsoft Graphs API

Tags: c#, .net, web, microsoft-graph-api

I have an older application I've been tasked to work with that utilizes the Microsoft graphs API to schedule calendar events for our employees. The purpose of the application is to monitor changes to production servers, when a new change request is added it gets added along with a list of implementers. Some implementers are "required" status for the change whereas others (mostly systems analysts) are added to the change for documentation purposes but are not actually required to be free during the time the change is pushed out.

I've been tasked with making it so that required implementers are marked as "Busy" during the change time on their outlook calendars, but non-required implementers are marked as "Free". However, it seems that the showAs status in the request (which is what controls whether the event shows as busy/free/etc) is at the calendar event level, not at the attendee level. Does anyone know if it is possible to make it so that different attendees to the same calendar event have different showAs statuses, or if the API is limited so that the event can only be "Busy" or "Free" as a whole for all attendees?

Snippet of the code (all attendees are required in this example but in other places they are not):

```
private static RootEmailObject ConvertApptItemToRootEmailObject(ApptItem apptItem)
{
    RootEmailObject jsonEmailObject = new RootEmailObject();
    jsonEmailObject.subject = apptItem.Subject;
    jsonEmailObject.allowNewTimeProposals = true;
    jsonEmailObject.transactionId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    jsonEmailObject.showAs = "Free";

    Start start = new Start()
    {
        dateTime = apptItem.Start,
        timeZone = "Eastern Standard Time"
    };
    jsonEmailObject.start = start;

    End end = new End()
    {
        dateTime = apptItem.End,
        timeZone = "Eastern Standard Time"
    };
    jsonEmailObject.end = end;

    jsonEmailObject.location = new Location()
    {
        displayName = apptItem.Location
    };

    jsonEmailObject.body = new Body()
    {
        contentType = "HTML",
        content = apptItem.Body
    };

    List<Attendee> attendeeList = new List<Attendee>();

    foreach (var attendee in apptItem.RequiredAttendees)
    {
        Attendee newAttendee = new Attendee()
        {
            emailAddress = new Emailaddress()
            {
                address = attendee,
                name = attendee.Substring(0, attendee.IndexOf("@"))
            },
            type = "Required"
        };

        attendeeList.Add(newAttendee);
    }

    jsonEmailObject.attendees = attendeeList.ToArray();

    return jsonEmailObject;
}
```